# KEEP THE DATABASE OPEN THROGHOUT THE OPERATION VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I need a method that will let me keep my MSaccess database open throughout the application operation instead of opening and closing everytime i enter data.
Currently `Dim provider As String Dim dataFile As String Dim connString As String Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand`
is public declared in each form . And the following is declared on private class

```
 provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        dataFile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SACCO\SACCO_DB.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "INSERT INTO STAFF([ID_NO],[FULL_NAME],[EMAIL],[PASSWORD]) Values(?,?,?,?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
```

This makes my application slower. Kindly, may someone guide me on how i will keep the database open on startup and closed on exit.

Comment: First let's take a step back...why are you using MS Access as the back-end for your application? It's mostly designed as a single-user, desktop database platform by itself, or as a frontend for something like a SQL Server database. It doesn't generally suit being the back-end for another application. There are better options you can choose for that.

Comment: How have you determined that that really is making your application slower?

Comment: @AndrewMorton the time it takes to open and close every single operation is significant. If it could stay open as the form loads, it would really save some time even if it's 2sec.

Comment: @Adyson because the client said so. Access is Graphical and he wanted to be able to access the database, and graphical reports.

Comment: Then what is the point of the VB application? You might as well do it all in the Access front-end.

Comment: P.S. `because the client said so` ... I respectfully disagree that the client always has the last word. Part of a programmer's job should be to guide the client to the best technical solution to their problem, no matter what solution they may have heard of and think they want. In this case their reasons are, on the face of it, ok-ish, but then again the application user should generally have no need to see the raw data, and there are plenty of other ways to build reports.

Comment: If it is taking more than about 0.1 seconds then there is very likely to be something else that is causing your application to be slow. [Measure app performance in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019) could help you check where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Opening and closing the connection every time you need to access the data is probably best practice.  After all the Connection implements IDisposable which is a fair indication that it should have a very short lifetime.  As others have suggested, if maintaining the connection like this is causing enough delay to be even noticeable there is something else at play.

Comment: Why are you not using an auto-increment field for the id?

Comment: You haven't showed us the rest of the code. Where is the connection opened? Where is the command executed? Where are the parameters added?

Comment: @Mary because I already have a method that generates random unique numbers and assigns to each user

Comment: I hope your method is returning a GUID but wouldn't it be cleaner to just use the auto-increment provided by the database?

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is a long time known issue - and we see near weekly postings about how LARGE delays can occur when opening the database. So for that 20+ years on a NEAR DAILY basis, from Access Front ends to back ends, the solution has been to force + keep a persistent connection. I can make a long post about how and why this occurs, but it has to do with the windows file system - and thus a open of the file, and Access attempting to open exclusive as it attempts to flip the use of the file into high speed single user mode can cause REALLY large delays. As noted, force and to keep the connection open is the near daily advice we see here for close to 20 years.

So, ok, we now using vb.net?

Simply declare a global var in a standard code module as public. Then in your startup code, you can do 1 of two things:

Open the database object - that means you don't have to know ahead of time to "pick" a particlar table to open.

eg this:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module MyGlobalCode

    Public gDBCon As OleDbConnection ' global connection object

    Public Sub GlobalOpenDatabase()
        gDBCon = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TESTAce)
        gDBCon.Open
    End Sub

    Public Sub GlobalCloseDatabase()
        gDBCon.Close()
    End Sub


End Module
```

So, now in any and all code? You use the above gDBCon and you:

Don't have to create a new connection object over and over.
You eliminate this LONG time known slow opening issue.

Now, it not clear why this big delay does NOT occur on some networks and setup - but, if it is occurring, then the above will show spectacular improvements in performance. Often the issue is even virus scanning software, and sometimes it seems to do with Active Directory. And other times, it has to do with VERY slow file creating times (each time you open the database, a ".ldb" file is also created - the time to create this file can be quite long on some systems - again a forced open connection will eliminate your software speeds being limited by external forces such as AD, or virus software, or a good number of other issues that causes this issue.

Comment: Kallal thanks alot for taking time to answer my question. Just need some clarification a little bit. After making the variable global, will it be right if I call in the variable on form btnclose and as well call it in form load when I launch the app?

Comment: Yes, the idea is a one time call in your startup routines. About the only issue is that some cmdSQL execute commands I believe will close the connection in some cases. This I don't have a through answer as to the cases when this occurs. As a result, in place of a global connect object, you would be safer to create a global function that returns the connection object, but could check if the object is open in that function, and if not then execute a .open again to deal with existing code that may have been designed around "normal" use in which connection object was closed or even disposed.